# Issue with script_score in Elasticsearch Query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I've encountered an issue while executing a query in Elasticsearch, specifically with the script_score section. Everything was functioning correctly until I incorporated the script_score component. Now, I consistently receive the following error:

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(meta.status, ApiError)(
elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')
```

Below is the query causing the problem:

```
    very_basic_query = {
        "size": 50,
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {"terms": {"general.source_application": ["twitter", "telegram"]}}
                        ],
                        "filter": [
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "general.start_time": {
                                        "gte": 0,
                                        "lte": 2200000000000
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "vectors",
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {"exists": {"field": "vectors.vector"}},
                                                {"match": {"vectors.type": "NLP"}}
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "script_score": {
                    "script": {
                        "source": "(cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, params.field) + 1.0)",
                        "params": {
                            "query_vector": query_vector,
                            "field": "vectors.vector"
                        },
    
                    }
                }
    
            }
        } 
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on what might be causing this runtime error and how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: There is a redundant comma after
                        "params": {
                            "query_vector": query_vector,
                            "field": "vectors.vector"
                        },
Do you have anything else there? What type does query_vector has? How is very_basic_query used? Which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think "query" block is missing right under "script_score".
I saw it on official documentation under cosine similarity.

[script_score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#vector-functions-cosine)

It says:

> To restrict the number of documents on which script score calculation is applied, provide a filter

I hope it works.

Comment: I try that.
Everytime I did I get this error: script_score query does not support [query]